# Subfigure to subfigure caption

Tags: captions, subfloats

I am new to LaTeX. I am not sure how to frame my question. But I will frame it so that it is understandable.

I would like to make a subfigure, but the caption must be

`caption of subfigure a-1`                `caption of subfigure a-2`

`caption of subfigure b-1`      `caption of subfigure b-2`

```
                 `caption  of entire figure`
```

I  tried using subfigure, but I am getting continuously `a,b,c,d`, but i need to name them as as mentioned above (a-1, a-2, b-1, b-2).  In my situation, there are chances that the sub figures might be in different pages.

Comment: There are several different subfigure and subcaption packages, but you really don't need any of them.  Just put them all into a tabular, then use a regular caption at the bottom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This uses the same idea as `subequations` of `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{parentsubcaption}
\newenvironment{subsubcaption}
 {\refstepcounter{sub\@captype}%
  \protected@edef\theparentsubcaption{\@nameuse{thesub\@captype}}%
  \setcounter{parentsubcaption}{\value{sub\@captype}}%
  \setcounter{sub\@captype}{0}%
  \@namedef{thesub\@captype}{\theparentsubcaption--\arabic{sub\@captype}}%
  \ignorespaces
}{%
  \setcounter{sub\@captype}{\value{parentsubcaption}}%
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subsubcaption}
\begin{subfigure}{5cm}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{caption of subfigure a--1}\label{a--1}
\end{subfigure}\qquad
\begin{subfigure}{5cm}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{caption of subfigure a--2}\label{a--2}
\end{subfigure}
\end{subsubcaption}

\begin{subsubcaption}
\begin{subfigure}{5cm}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{caption of subfigure b--1}\label{b--1}
\end{subfigure}\qquad
\begin{subfigure}{5cm}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{caption of subfigure b--2}\label{b--2}
\end{subfigure}
\end{subsubcaption}

\caption{caption  of entire figure}
\end{figure}

References:
\ref{a--1} and \subref{a--1};
\ref{b--1} and \subref{b--1}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

### EDIT

The above code doesn't really work if more figure environments use `subsubcaption`. Here's a workaround that tries to work well also with `\ContinuedFloat`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newif\ifsubsubcaption@ContinuedFloat
\newif\ifsubsubcaption@nonfirst
\patchcmd{\ContinuedFloat}
  {\caption@ContinuedFloat}
  {\subsubcaption@ContinuedFloattrue\caption@ContinuedFloat}
  {}{}

\newcounter{parentsubcaption}
\newenvironment{subsubcaption}
 {\refstepcounter{sub\@captype}%
  \protected@edef\theparentsubcaption{\@nameuse{thesub\@captype}}%
  \setcounter{parentsubcaption}{\value{sub\@captype}}%
  \setcounter{sub\@captype}{0}%
  \@namedef{thesub\@captype}{\theparentsubcaption--\arabic{sub\@captype}}%
  \ignorespaces
}{%
  \setcounter{sub\@captype}{\value{parentsubcaption}}%
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{subsubcaption}{%
  \ifsubsubcaption@ContinuedFloat
  \else
    \ifsubsubcaption@nonfirst
    \else
      \subsubcaption@nonfirsttrue
      \setcounter{sub\@captype}{0}%
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subsubcaption}
\begin{subfigure}{5cm}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{caption of subfigure a--1}\label{a--1}
\end{subfigure}\qquad
\begin{subfigure}{5cm}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{caption of subfigure a--2}\label{a--2}
\end{subfigure}
\end{subsubcaption}

\begin{subsubcaption}
\begin{subfigure}{5cm}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{caption of subfigure b--1}\label{b--1}
\end{subfigure}\qquad
\begin{subfigure}{5cm}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{caption of subfigure b--2}\label{b--2}
\end{subfigure}
\end{subsubcaption}

\caption{caption  of entire figure}
\end{figure}

References:
\ref{a--1} and \subref{a--1};
\ref{b--1} and \subref{b--1}.

\begin{figure}
\ContinuedFloat
\centering
\begin{subsubcaption}
\begin{subfigure}{5cm}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{caption of subfigure c--1}\label{c--1}
\end{subfigure}\qquad
\begin{subfigure}{5cm}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{caption of subfigure c--2}\label{c--2}
\end{subfigure}
\end{subsubcaption}

\begin{subsubcaption}
\begin{subfigure}{5cm}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{caption of subfigure d--1}\label{d--1}
\end{subfigure}\qquad
\begin{subfigure}{5cm}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{caption of subfigure d--2}\label{d--2}
\end{subfigure}
\end{subsubcaption}

\caption{caption  of entire figure (continued)}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subsubcaption}
\begin{subfigure}{5cm}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{caption of subfigure a--1}\label{a--1-x}
\end{subfigure}\qquad
\begin{subfigure}{5cm}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{caption of subfigure a--2}\label{a--2-x}
\end{subfigure}
\end{subsubcaption}

\begin{subsubcaption}
\begin{subfigure}{5cm}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{caption of subfigure b--1}\label{b--1-x}
\end{subfigure}\qquad
\begin{subfigure}{5cm}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{caption of subfigure b--2}\label{b--2-x}
\end{subfigure}
\end{subsubcaption}

\caption{caption  of entire figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The “continuation” figure has labels c and d, while the following “new” one has a and b again.

Comment: @egreg..Thank you very much. This is what I was expecting.      1. But, for me, the counter is starting from c (Eg: c-1,c-2): 2. Also I have multiple subfigures. The figures are not moving automatically to next page, instead the sub-figures are in bottom margin of the current page.  For this I tried to remove '\ignorespacesafterend', but this doesn't help me.

Comment: @user8162 A `figure` environment is never split across pages. You can look at `\ContinuedFloat` in `caption`.

Comment: Thanks.. \continuedfloat worked fine. I am extremely sorry for asking more questions. But still the counter starts from c.

Comment: @user8162 For the counter starting from c we need a minimal example. Open a new question.