# caption of the subcaption starts from 'c'

Tags: subfloats

*Edited

I am using the subcaption as mentioned in this link

[Subfigure to subfigure caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217927/subfigure-to-subfigure-caption)

I am expecting the caption to start from 'a', but the caption starts from 'c'. Any help would be appreciable.

```
\makeatletter
\newcounter{parentsubcaption}
\newenvironment{subsubcaption}
 {\refstepcounter{sub\@captype}%
  \protected@edef\theparentsubcaption{\@nameuse{thesub\@captype}}%
  \setcounter{parentsubcaption}{\value{sub\@captype}}%
  \setcounter{sub\@captype}{0}%
  \@namedef{thesub\@captype}{\theparentsubcaption--\arabic{sub\@captype}}%
 % \ignorespaces
}{%
  \setcounter{sub\@captype}{\value{parentsubcaption}}%
  %\ignorespacesafterend
}
\makeatother

\begin{figure*}[!htb]

------------------------------------
\begin{subsubcaption}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=2.3in]{fig1.eps}
\caption{} %\label{4.1 a}
\end{subfigure}% 

 ~
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=2.15in]{fig2.eps} % 
\caption{} %\label{4.1 b}
\end{subfigure}
\end{subsubcaption}

%--------------------------------
\begin{subsubcaption}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=2.3in]{fig3.eps}
\caption{} %\label{4.1 a}
\end{subfigure} 
 ~
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=2.15in]{fig4.eps} % 
\caption{} %\label{4.1 b}
\end{subfigure}
\end{subsubcaption}
\caption{} 
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}[!t]
%-------------------------------------------------------
\begin{subsubcaption}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=2.3in]{fig5.eps}
\caption{Est. $F_c$ of Original Speech Signal} %\label{4.1 a}
\end{subfigure}%
~
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=2.15in]{fig6.eps} % 
\caption{} 
\end{subfigure}
\end{subsubcaption}

\nopagebreak
%------------------ 
\begin{subsubcaption}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=2.3in]{fig7.eps}
\caption{} %\label{4.1 a}
\end{subfigure}%
~
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=2.15in]{fig8.eps} % 
\caption{} %\label{4.1 b}
\end{subfigure}
\end{subsubcaption}
\caption{} 
\end{figure*}
```

This code is working fine. i.e. Caption starting from 'a'. But if i copy the same code and make an another set of figure. I was expecting it to start from 'a', but it continues from 'c'

Comment: Please give us your MWE.

Comment: I'll fix the code in the other answer soon! Thanks for noting.

Comment: The code is fixed. If you're satisfied with the edit, we can close this question as duplicate.

Comment: @egreg.. Thank you very much.. It works perfectly..

Comment: @user8162 So I voted for closing; you had my upvote, of course.

Comment: @egreg.. I can give 100000000 likes for your edits in..http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217927/subfigure-to-subfigure-caption